# Hyperref warning when combined with package titlesec

Tags: hyperref, titlesec

How can one get rid of the hyperref warning about the `$` signs in the subsection title that are generated in the following minimal example?

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec}            
\usepackage{titletoc}                
%\newcommand{\subsecformat}[1]{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{
%    \normalsize\selectfont
%    \filright\textcolor{black}{\textsc{#1}}}}    
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Can light move faster than $c$?}
No.
\end{document}
```

Probably the command `\subsecformat` needs to be improved. How should this be done?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `titlesec`. Use `\texorpdfstring{$c$}{c}` or ignore the warning. By the way, defining `\subsecformat` does exactly nothing.

Comment: Just for completeness, the answer is to write \texorpdfstring{$c$}{c} in the title, in order to get the PDF bookmarks right.